# nginx proxy_pass (to asp.net core blazor) not work with css

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-redirect

I'm neither familiar with nginx nor asp.net core. but i'm trying with both.

My nginx server is using default configurations, serving several very simple html pages on 80 port. Currently the homepage is: http://leiyang.icu or https://leiyang.icu.

One net5 built in [asp.net core blazor sample app](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/create) is hosted in a different location from nginx document root, and works well: http://leiyang.icu:8080/

The **goal** is redirecting:

> $host/net --> $host:8080

> $host/net/counter --> $host:8080/counter

> $host/net/anything --> $host:8080/anything

and so on, while keeping the url in browser.

I've tried simple `rewrite` rule

```sh
rewrite /net(.*) http://leiyang.icu:8080/$1 permanent;
```

but it shows redirected url in browser, which is not expected.

I tried `proxy_pass` following [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-5.0). now if user go to http://leiyang.icu/net/, he can see the page, but css is not loaded(screeshot attached).

```sh
location /net/ {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

[image: css is not loaded]

I guess possible reason is my `proxy_pass` configuration didn't specify different document roots.

But I cannot figure out how to solve. Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: Use `rewrite ... break;` for an internal rewrite instead of a 301 redirect.

Comment: doesn't work, use `...break` i still got redirected url http://leiyang.icu:8080// in browser.